# Prometheus query to get % of each range

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

We are storing the number of chars entered by the user using prometheus histogram in the following fashion. I'm having hard time to get % of 1 char entered compared to the total chars entered.

```
number_of_char_distribution_bucket{country="GB",le="1.0",} 1
number_of_char_distribution_bucket{country="GB",le="2.0",} 3
number_of_char_distribution_bucket{country="GB",le="3.0",} 5
number_of_char_distribution_bucket{country="GB",le="4.0",} 5
number_of_char_distribution_bucket{country="GB",le="5.0",} 5

number_of_char_distribution_count 9
```

I have the following query and it shows only the number of char distribution

```
sum(increase(number_of_char_distribution_bucket{_namespace_="addautcmp",vendor_name="ADA"}[24h])) by (le)
```

I need to get this data in a bar graph, currently it is a guage.

Comment: Have you checked https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns the number of times users entered one char over the last 24 hours:

```
sum(increase(number_of_char_distribution_bucket{le="1.0"}[24h]))
```

The following query returns the total number of times users entered any number of chars over the last 24 hours:

```
sum(increase(number_of_char_distribution_count[24h]))
```

Just divide the first query by the second query in order to get percentage (in the range `[0...1]`) of times when users entered just one char:

```
sum(increase(number_of_char_distribution_bucket{le="1.0"}[24h]))
  /
sum(increase(number_of_char_distribution_count[24h]))
```

If you need calculating the percentage of times users entered exactly two chars, then use the following query:

```
(
  sum(increase(number_of_char_distribution_bucket{le="2.0"}[24h]))
    -
  sum(increase(number_of_char_distribution_bucket{le="1.0"}[24h]))
)
  /
sum(increase(number_of_char_distribution_count[24h]))
```

This query subtracts the number of times users entered 1 (`le="1.0"`) from the number of times users entered 1 or 2 chars (`le="2.0"`) in order to get the number of times users entered exactly 2 chars, and then divides it by the total number of times users entered any number of chars.

See [these docs about Prometheus histograms](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) for more details.